# error: clusterrole must be specified

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I am trying to get the Kubernetes Dashboard running, but I am running into trouble with no `clusterrole` being specified.

> kubectl create clusterrolebinding add-on-cluster-admin
>   --serviceaccount=kube-system:kubernetes-dashboard-minimal

error: clusterrole must be specified

Answer (score 0):

yes, the `--clusterrole` flag is required